# add this event to the tool bar

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In `TinyMCE` how do I add this event to the toolbar id?

```
// Adds a click handler to the current document
tinymce.dom.Event.add(document.getElementById('test'), 'click', function (e) {
    alert('test - tool bar clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question has the same goal as your other one. My answer might not be of help for that special purpose. Well, here it is:

```
$('#' + your_editor_id + '_toolbargroup').bind('click', function(){
    alert('test - tool bar clicked');
})
```